# How to manage webapps footprint in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-management, out-of-memory

I'm looking for a runtime solution for finding memory usage of web apps.
I'm providing a framework that includes tomcat on which different clients deploys several web apps. sometimes one of them consumes a lot of memory, thus crushing the entire process.
I would like to have a manager web app (like the tomcat's manager) that will detect this and maybe undeploy \ re-deploy the problematic webapp.
another solution (I don't think it's possible) is to allocate a slice of the heap to each web app separately.

Demanding the clients to change the existing web apps is possible, but I'd rather not to.

any thoughts?

Comment: Why not run each one in a separate tomcat instance so that the rogue application won't affect others? You can run an apache as a proxy to these individual tomcat instances.

Comment: On my tomcat there are 6 webapps, and we can't efford the overhead of 6 new processes.

Comment: Then deploy 2 Tomcats with 3 webapps each, or 3 Tomcats with 2 webapps, or some other combination. The situation will be better anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't intercept the allocations in each webapp, and there are no callbacks from the garbage collector, so you can't know how much memory each webapp uses. I think you're better off deploying several Tomcat instances, so that one "rogue" webapp does not kill all the others (up to one Tomcat per webapp, but you can also create groups to limit the number of instances, depending on the criticity of your different applications).

Answer (score 1):

Tomact runs as single java process so it is hard to allocate memory per application. You can increase [MaxPermSize,-Xmx](https://serverfault.com/questions/139435/where-to-set-java-heap-options-e-g-xmx-for-tomcat-6-under-ubuntu-9-04) only.

You can check [leak detector for Tomcat](http://java-monitor.com/forum/showthread.php?t=818) but it will hardly help since you can not change source code of other apps.

Comment: I can change the code (I just rather not to...) the leak detector won't solve this because 1. it's static and I need a solution at runtime, 2. it's looking at the perm memory andI'm short on the heap.

Comment: Then I guess you can do profiling using [Jprofiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/java-profiler-JEE.html) of tomcat and fix problems. And if you think that this is long shot then just restart tomcat after fixed duration :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to look at would be VisualVM, this will give you an overview of Tomcats memory usage in the JVM.

http://techblog.zabuchy.net/2012/monitoring-of-tomcat-with-visualvm-and-visualgc/